# Filtering columns from two diff tables after join

Tags: sql

I wanted to know best method to filter below when the filter has columns from 2 diff tables that have been joined, I know the first table cols should be filtered in the where clause and the second table in join in the on clause after join. But what if it is like below?

```
select e.name as employeename, m.name as managername
from employee e
left join employee m
on e.mgr_id = m.emp_id
where e.doj < m.doj
```

or

```
select e.name as employeename, m.name as managername
from employee e
left join employee m
on e.mgr_id = m.emp_id and e.doj < m.doj
```

Thanks

Comment: The first one turns the outer join into an inner join

Comment: The first returns all employees.  The second returns all employees with managers.  You should use the version that does what you want.  If you want the second, though, use an `inner join` rather than an outer join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second case will return you more rows where m.name will be null.

The thing is the first query joins tables and filters records afterwards.
Whereas in the second query you're filtering records from the m table out before joining them. Thus, there will be less records in m table to match with records in e

Here is an example. Employee table looks something like this

| name | emp_id | mgr_id | doj |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 | 10 |
| B | 2 | 3 | 100 |
| C | 3 | null | 50 |

1. When you self-left join this using first query

   select e.name as employeename, m.name as managername
   from employee e
   left join employee m
   on e.mgr_id = m.emp_id
   where e.doj < m.doj

It does the following:
Step 1. It looks for records where e.mgr_id = m.emp_id

| emp_name | mgr_name | doj |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | C | 10 |
| B | C | 100 |
| C | null | 50 |

Step 2. It removes lines that not satisfy criteria "e.doj < m.doj" from the output of step 1. So the overall output will be (I've added the "doj" column to the output to make it more clear)

| emp_name | mgr_name | doj |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | C | 10 |

2. When you're using the second query against same table, the DB will first filter all the lines from "m" table that do not satisfy the criteria

   e.mgr_id = m.emp_id and e.doj < m.doj

So, there will be only 1 line from the M table to join with

| name | emp_id | mgr_id | doj |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 | 10 |

But since this is not just a join, but left join, the database will just fill "unjoined" columns with nulls and the output will be

| emp_name | mgr_name | doj |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | C | 10 |
| B | null | null |
| C | null | null |